# SQL -5 minutes from a existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

How can I substract the column "begin_execution" with 5 minutes?
The begin_execution-Datetime will filled via an SQL-Task, but i need this time -5 minutes to check the running compatibility.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM queue_entry WHERE begin_execution - GETDATE()-5min AND STATUS = 'not solved'
```

**Thats the original output:**

2016-06-09 15:00:11.4070000

**i need this output (-5 minutes):**

2016-06-09 14:55:11.4070000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE begin_execution >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

Comment: More info can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx